# How to run import tests when using a recipe? (not with bdist_conda)

Tags: conda, conda-build

I'm using conda-build to build a python package using a recipe (i.e. a `meta.yaml` file).

I would like conda-build to automatically discover and run import tests on all the modules in the package, just as it does when using `bdist_conda` (see https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/recipes/build-without-recipe.html#import-tests).  However, I'm using a recipe. Is this possible?

Comment: I assume your modules are too numerous to manually enumerate them out?

Comment: Not too numerous, but it is important that they are discovered automatically (in case a module is added).